# Log multiple occurences of one HTTP header with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

With **mod_log** you can log headers sent back to the client in the access.log file with the `%{Set-Cookie}o` directive. But if there are **multiple occurences** of the same header, as is [authorized by the HTTP RPC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), **only one gets logged**.

How can we have **all of them** logged ?

For reference, the RFC states :

> Multiple message-header fields with
>   the same field-name MAY be present in
>   a message if and only if the entire
>   field-value for that header field is
>   defined as a comma-separated list
>   [i.e., #(values)].

`Set-Cookie` is such a field-name since the field-value is comma-separated. I would not mind to have them joined together as suggested in the HTTP RPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, since version 2.0, It works out-of-the-box, except for `Content-type` : every header gets nicely concatenated with a comma as suggested in the HTTP RFC.

The "Set-Cookie" response header also has a special treatment as we can see in the `log_header_out` function of `modules/loggers/mod_log_config.c` :

```
// ... start of snippet ...
if (!strcasecmp(a, "Content-type") && r->content_type) {
    cp = ap_field_noparam(r->pool, r->content_type);
}
else if (!strcasecmp(a, "Set-Cookie")) {
    cp = find_multiple_headers(r->pool, r->headers_out, a);
}
else {
    cp = apr_table_get(r->headers_out, a);
}
// ... end of snippet ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of apache? what version of mod_log?  The correct answer may be to either file a bug report with apache or patch it in yourself.

Comment: Yeah, i was stuck with a 1.3. But when I tried with 2.2 it worked flawlessly, hence my answer.

Comment: +1 since it doesn't answers, but made me think about trying with another version :-)